# PHP LINKQ Fails

Tags: php, linq

This lines of code are on a Php Linq  LinqToObjects example:

```
$names = array("John", "Peter", "Joe", "Patrick", "Donald", "Eric");
echo 'elementAt(2): ' . from('$name')->in($names)->elementAt(2) . "\r\n";
```

And poduce this error

```
Message: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given
Filename: PHPLinq/LinqToObjects.php
Line Number: 669
```

Php linkq is old (2009) and maybe don't work fine in my version 5.3.2

How i can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix it by change in the PHPLinq/LinqToObjects.php Line 669

```
if (count($result) > 0) {
    return array_shift($result);
    }
```

whit:

```
if (count($result) > 0) {
            if(is_array($result)){
        return array_shift($result);
            }else{
                return $result;
            }
    }
```

Anyway the library is unsuported and poor documented.